# SQL SELECT DISTINCT and GROUP BY problem

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

I need to return only 1 row per specific database entry. For e.g. if I have:

```
ID col1 col2
1    1    A
2    1    B
3    1    C
4    2    D
5    3    E
6    4    F
7    4    G
```

in MySQL I can run a query

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM table GROUP BY col1
```

and I will get ->

```
ID col1 col2
1    1    A
4    2    D
5    3    E
6    4    F
```

which is what I want, but if I run the same query in SQL Server I get an error..

So, basically I need to return only ONE (or FIRST) "col1" AND its "col2" from each row in the table..

What would be the correct syntax for SQL Server?

Thank you for your time!

Andrej

EDIT:

the complete query that works in mysql is ->

```
SELECT DISTINCT list_order, category_name, category_id
FROM  `jos_vm_category` 
WHERE  `category_publish` =  'Y'
GROUP BY list_order
```

so, FOR EACH "list_order" number i want to return the category_name and category_id from that row, and ignore every other row with the same "list_order" number

Comment: @marc_s: I guess the error the OP gets is that SQL Server requires all the `SELECT` fields to appear in the `GROUP BY` clause, unless they are part of an aggregate function. MySQL does not require this.

Comment: in MSSQL the error is "Column 'jos_vm_category.category_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function in T-SQL, which allows you to "partition" your data by something - like your `col1` here - and get incremental numbers for each of those data partitions. If you want only the first entry for each "partition", just query it this way (using a Common Table Expression - CTE):

```
;WITH Distincts AS
(
    SELECT ID, col1, col2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY ID) AS 'RowNo'
    FROM dbo.Table
)
SELECT
    ID, col1, col2
FROM
    Distincts
WHERE
    RowNo = 1
```

This gives me the output you're looking for.

Comment: looks like I'm late :).. but theres a simpler alternative

Comment: @Roopesh - Your alternative is less efficient and I wouldn't agree that it is simpler either.

Comment: @Martin - I disagree - posting a query plan comparison within my answer.

Comment: @roopesh - The "Query cost relative to the batch" is not a reliable indicator as it is based on cardinality **estimates** even in the actual execution plan. Did you bother populating the tables? If so what is your script for that? What do `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` say? Also add sensible indexes to get rid of that `sort` in the plan!

Comment: @Martin - :( it shows 0ms for both queries with the above data, il have to populate a lot more data for it to show any meaningful comparison. It does show 2 scans and 8 logical reads vs 1 scan and 1 logical read for marc's query, but i figured in memory processing would be more.

Comment: Also, I tried with a unique index on id column execution plan estimates remain same. Let me get back to you with a lot more data in that table and with the id as a primary key.

Comment: @roopesh - To be fair a nested loops plan could turn out better if each group is very large but I think you would need to use `cross apply` to get this plan.

Comment: @Martin - nope.. guess you were right all along, at least for the data that I generated. Serves me right for believing the estimated costs. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all rows corresponding to the first instance of a value in col1 as follows

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table t1
where not exists 
      (select 1 
         from table t2
        where t2.col1 = t1.col1 and
              t2.id < t1.id)
```

EDIT: posting a comparison of the queries
[image]

EDIT2: Posting the comparison of actual query execution plan, with about 2000 rows of data randomly generated, and with a id being a identity column with a unique index. A second index on id and col1. 
[image]

Turns out Marc's query is faster after all, at least with this data!